# code works fine in javascript but not in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

when i execute

```
"document.getElementsByClassName("jobs-company-card__cta-link ember-view");"
```

in the console (javascript)  it returns the elements by that class name but when i execute :

`driver.findElements(By.className("jobs-company-card__content-wrapper"));`

the result (element) is an empty List , noting is returned

Comment: Can you upload your html page code here

Comment: it is the linkedin job page : https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/ ;

Comment: Have you used the same class name "jobs-company-card__cta-link ember-view" which you used while trying with console ?

Comment: Provide few seconds of wait before click on this element. For wait use `Explicit wait` method.

Comment: @dali Which particular element does it belong to on this linkedIn page?

Comment: javascript code :   
        var aTags = document.getElementsByClassName("jobs-company-card__content-wrapper");
      found = aTags[1];
found.click();
works perfectly 

selenium code driver.findElements(By.className("jobs-company-card__content-wrapper"));
does not

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED 
all i had to do is add this

```
                    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20 );
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.jobs-company-card__content-wrapper")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS selectors instead?

`driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".jobs-company-card__content-wrapper"));`

Comment: yes i did 
 "   driver.findElementByCssSelector("div.jobs-company-card__content-wrapper").click();"